# Verifying statements for non-zero matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $N$ be non-zero $3 \times 3$ matrix with the property $N^2=0$. Which of the following is true?

(A) $N$ is not similar to a diagonal matrix.

(B) $N$ is similar to diagonal matrix.

(C) $N$ has one non-zero eigenvector.

(D) $N$ has three linearly independent eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N\ne0$ implies its minimal polynomial is $x^2$ whose roots are not distinct.

Therefore $N$ is not diagonalizble.

Consequently $B,D$ are false and $A$ is true.

Since $N$ has a eigenvalue $0,$ $C$ is true by definition.

Comment: I take it we are reading C as "$N$ has at least one non-zero eigenvector".

Comment: At least that's how I interpreted $(C).$